# Taking a textView's characters and adding each letter into an array

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, textview

I'm making an iPhone app and I have been able to add each letter when it is typed in but not if text is pasted in.
Any ideas?

Comment: Typed in to what? What sort of control? What do you mean by 'add each letter'? Try making your question clearer.

Comment: sorry I was talking about a textview, but it's mute now that I have the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *string = @"abcdef";
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i=0; i<string.length; i++) {
    [array addObject:[string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)]];
}
NSLog(@"array: %2@", array);
```

NSLog output:

```
array: (
        a,
        b,
        c,
        d,
        e,
        f
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are truly using an `UITextView`, this is your friend:

`textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:`

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextViewDelegate/textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:

Comment: thats what I am using. I can make my program work, but the user has to type in everything I want them to be able to copy and past then be able to loop through every letter.